# Bind HTML table on button click again

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have HTML table in my Codebehind which will bind data on pageload.

now i have one button to insert data into database. my problem is when i am inserting data on button click, my page get postback. my html table data will show only old data not new one which i have added. because html table binds first in pageload and after words my control will go to button_click event.

I tried to put ispostback on page_load but then first time when page get loads html table dose not display any data.

how can i solve this problem.

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Ticket";
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // //Building an HTML string.
                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

                //Table start.

                html.Append("<table id='tbldata' style='table-layout:fixed;' border='0'>");
                html.Append("<THEAD>");
                html.Append("<TR>");
                html.Append("<TH>Ticket</TH>");
                html.Append("<TH>Priority</TH>");
                html.Append("<TH>Status<div class='fildownarrow'></div></TH>");
                html.Append("<TH>Practice Name<div class='fildownarrow'></div></TH>");
                html.Append("<TH>Patient Name</TH>");
                html.Append("<TH>Assigned</TH>");
                html.Append("<TH>Subject</TH>");
                html.Append("<TH style='width:100px;><a href='#'><div class='filtericon'></div></a></TH>");
                html.Append("</TR>");
                html.Append("</THEAD>");

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        html.Append("<tbody>");
                        html.Append("<tr>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Ticket_no"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Priority"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Status"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Practice_Name"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Patient_Name"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Assign_User_Name"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("<td>" + dr["Msg_Subject"] + "</td>");
                        html.Append("</tr>");
                        html.Append("</tbody>");
                    }
                }

                //Table end.
                html.Append("</table>");

                //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });

                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: dont do it this way, retrieve the data into a list and bind it to a listview control. will save you loads of trouble.

Comment: use SqlDataAdapter to retrive data and use Repeater, DataList or GridView to display data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should organize your code behind in this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Write data to database
    LoadData();
}

private void LoadData()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        //Here goes your sql code that reads the database
    }
}
```

Of course a better solution would be to use a control like a GridView and bind the data directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get empty table on page load when you check for IsPostBack property, I think you are checking if it's value is true. So table will only be loaded on postback. You should check if IsPostBack property value is false to display content only page's first load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Ticket";
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.

            html.Append("<table id='tbldata' style='table-layout:fixed;' border='0'>");
            html.Append("<THEAD>");
            html.Append("<TR>");
            html.Append("<TH>Ticket</TH>");
            html.Append("<TH>Priority</TH>");
            html.Append("<TH>Status<div class='fildownarrow'></div></TH>");
            html.Append("<TH>Practice Name<div class='fildownarrow'></div></TH>");
            html.Append("<TH>Patient Name</TH>");
            html.Append("<TH>Assigned</TH>");
            html.Append("<TH>Subject</TH>");
            html.Append("<TH style='width:100px;><a href='#'><div class='filtericon'></div></a></TH>");
            html.Append("</TR>");
            html.Append("</THEAD>");

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    html.Append("<tbody>");
                    html.Append("<tr>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Ticket_no"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Priority"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Status"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Practice_Name"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Patient_Name"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Assign_User_Name"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("<td>" + dr["Msg_Subject"] + "</td>");
                    html.Append("</tr>");
                    html.Append("</tbody>");
                }
            }

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this wont work. his table is created here, which means that it will not get updated on postbacks at all.

Comment: @Banana Oh, you're right. Seems like that I've misunderstood the question.